# unit of ~linearUpdate parameter in slam_gmapping?

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping, parameter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

Does anyone know what's the unit of ~linearUpdate parameter in slam_gmapping? and what does it mean?

Best regards

Hossain

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99946/unit-of-%7Elinearupdate-parameter-in-slam_gmapping?/) by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to REP 103 (http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) units in ROS should always be SI units. In this case, linearUpdate is in meters, as it is a distance traveled by the robot.

Setting this value lower will cause gmapping to update more frequently (say, every 0.25 or 0.5m of travel). Setting it to a higher number means less frequent updates. Less frequent updates are nice for reducing the memory/processor usage, however, if you have a short range laser or very poor odometry, it may cause the scan matcher to fail if the robot goes too far between updates.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cognitiveRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6861/cognitiverobot/) on 2013-11-11**:
Thanks Fergs for your reply. In slam_gmapping, linearUpdate is 1 by default. Do it mean it updates global map after every 1m travel? Does it mean it ignore laserScan which are saved before each 1 meter?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2013-11-12**:
Thats exactly what it means. Once you move 1m, gmapping will use that laserscan in the map building process. If you are using a 30m laser like the UTM30 on the PR2, 1m is fine. If you're using something like a kinect or smaller Hokuyo laser, 0.25 or 0.5 is pretty common.